# filament select with two columns

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament, google-filament

How could you configure the filament select component so that I get the first and last name?

```
    public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Select::make('customer_id')
                    ->relationship('customer', 'name')
                    ->searchable(['name', 'surname'])
                    ->preload()
                    ->required()
                    ->createOptionForm([
                        TextInput::make('name')
                            ->required()
                            ->label('Nombre'),
                        TextInput::make('surname')
                        ->required(),
                        TextInput::make('lastname')
                        ->label('Last Name')
                    ]),
            ]);
    }
```

I tried with an array but it doesn't work

`->relationship('customer', ['name', 'lastname'])`

Comment: ->relationship('customer', \DB::raw("CONCAT(name, ' ', lastname) as full_name"))

Answer (score 2):

You can ues this function `formatStateUsing()`, like this example:

```
Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('first_name')
    ->label(__('student.full_name'))
    ->formatStateUsing(function ($state, \App\Models\Student $student) {
        return $student->first_name . ' ' . $student->last_name;
}),
```